# Decompose(Normalize) 1 table into 2 tables

Tags: sql

I am having following table with near about 25000 records.

```
Table Namee: tblStdCods
Table Columns: id, Place, STD Code, State
```

Is there any way to decompose table into two like this WITHOUT AFFECTING DATA STORED IN IT,

```
tblStdCodes: id, Place, stadcode, stateId
tblState: stateId, stateName 

Original Table :

id    Place        STDCode   State
1     Ahmednagar    414003   Maharashtra

Resultanat Tables :

table 1: 
id    Place        STDCode   State
1     Ahmednagar    414003   1

table 2:

stateId  stateName
1        Maharashtra
```

Comment: Your original table has 4 columns in it yet your 2 tables have 6 columns combined, Please could you expand your question with some examples of original data and the desired result when the table is split into 2 (showing the id/stateId relationship preferably too)

Comment: @mike stateid column in both tables is for reference purpose ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create two tables with the structure you desire and after that you can simply Insert data from the old table, like this :

```
//tblState have the field stateName of type int AUTO_INCREMENT
INSERT INTO tblState (stateName) SELECT State FROM tblStdCods GROUP BY State;  

//Insert records with the pointer to the state table
INSERT INTO tblStdCodes (Id,Place, stadcode, stateId) SELECT Id, Place, STD Code, stateID FROM 
tblStdCods JOIN tblState ON State = stateName
```

The fields type of the two resultant tables will be derived from the original table, the only thing to be careful about is to have the AUTO_INCREMENT on the `stateID` field of the `tblState` table, in this way the database will generate automatically for you id's ...